# RANGE_DELETE and RANGE_ADD on connections with arguments

Tags: graphql, relayjs

I'm trying to achieve a mutation which is a RANGE_DELETE on a connection, but only on the specified arguments.

Scenario : the logged user, `Viewer` can see requests from others users and approve them.

The `User` type has a field `viewableRequests`, which is a relay connection, and with an extra optional argument `state`, which will filter the requests and only keep the one with the corresponding state.

Schema :

```
type User {
  id: ID
  viewableRequests(first: Int, [...], state: RequestStateEnum): ViewableRequestsConnection
}

type ViewableRequestsConnection {
  edges: [RequestEdge]
  ...
}

type RequestEdge {
  cursor: GraphQLString
  node: Request
}

type Request {
  id: ID
  user_id: Int
  state: RequestStateEnum
}

enum RequestStateEnum {
  pending
  approved
}
```

So if I call `viewableRequests(state: pending)`, I only get requests with the pending state, and if I call `viewableRequests(state: approved)`, I only get the the requests with the approved state.

How can I write a `ApproveRequest` mutation that will do a RANGE_DELETE on the `viewableRequests(state: pending)` connection, and a RANGE_ADD on the `viewableRequests(state: approved)` connection, and how should I shape the `getOptimisticResponse()` method ?

Here is my mutation schema :

```
type ApproveRequestInput {
  requestId: ID
}

type ApproveRequestPayload {
  viewer: User
  approvedRequest: Request
}

mutation {
  approveRequest($input: ApproveRequestInput): ApproveRequestPayload
}
```

Here is my current code :

```
import Relay, {
  Mutation,
} from 'react-relay';

export default class ApproveRequestMutation extends Mutation {
  static fragments = {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        id
      }
    `,
    request: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Request {
        id
      }
    `,
  };

  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation { approveRequest }`;
  }

  getVariables() {
    return {
      requestId: this.props.request.id,
    };
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on ApproveRequestPayload @relay(pattern: true) {
        viewer {
          pendingRequests: viewableRequests(state: pending)
          approvedRequests: viewableRequests(state: approved)
        }
        approvedRequest
      }
    `;
  }

  getOptimisticResponse() {
    return {
      // What should I write here ?
    };
  }

  getConfigs() {
    // The RANGE_DELETE config is not working ; how can I make it work ?
    return [{
      type: 'RANGE_DELETE',
      parentName: 'viewer',
      parentID: this.props.viewer.id,
      connectionName: 'pendingRequests',
      deletedIDFieldName: ['approvedRequest'],
      pathToConnection: ['viewer', 'pendingRequests'],
    }];
    // How can I can add here a RANGE_ADD config for the `approvedRequests` connection ?
    // I guess I must add an `approvedRequestEdge` on the mutation payload, but what is the config then ?
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a very similar setup. One user sees cases in the `IN_PROGRESS` state until he submits. When he does, I want it to move from `IN_PROGRESS` to `WAITING`. I've just got it to work by having the following configs :

```
return [
  {
    type: "FIELDS_CHANGE",
    fieldIDs: {
      case: this.props.caseId
    }
  },
  {
    type: "RANGE_ADD",
    parentName: "viewer",
    parentID: this.props.viewer.__dataID__, // eslint-disable-line
    connectionName: "cases",
    edgeName: "case",
    rangeBehaviors: {
      "": "refetch",
      "type(IN_PROGRESS)": "remove",
      "type(WAITING)": "prepend"
    }
  }
];
```

I'm guessing replacing `type(IN_PROGRESS)` by your `state(pending)` should work!

Comment: Sorry for not ticking this answer before. I've switched to Relay Modern since then but this looks like it would work with Relay Classic !